# PC stuck in an infinite BSOD/Reboot loop

Tags: windows-10, hardware-failure, bsod, reboot, infinite-loop

Everything started when I was playing Overwatch yesterday afternoon.
During a game, the image froze and sound was looping indefinitely. So I restarted my computer, and got a BSOD on startup : IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL. After the PC restarted again, i launched the game and after 5 minutes it froze, saying "Overwatch crashed in the graphics driver [...]"
Then a few minutes later I got another BSOD : PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA.

After that I could only use my computer for 5-10 minutes between each restarts before a BSOD appeared, either KMODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED or IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL.

I thought there was a problem with my GPU driver so I downloaded the new one from nVidia's website, but halfway through installation my PC crashed again.

Now I'm stuck in a BSOD loop, preventing me from getting to the windows login screen. 
I can enter and modify Bios, but can't boot in safe mode because it also leads to a BSOD.

I have tried booting from an install CD and via USB, but I get yet another BSOD after clicking either on the install windows or the repair option.

I get this problem with and without my main HDD (where windows 10 is installed) connected.

I have tried booting with one ram stick at a time, and ran memtest86 with 0 errors after 4 passes. (Should I let it run for longer?)

I also tried booting after disconnecting the GPU, but the PC kept rebooting over and over.

My specs :

```
I9-9900k 
MSI Meg Ace Z390
G. Skill Trident Z Royal 16GB 3200Mhz CL14
Asus Rog Strix 1080ti OC
Main drive WD Black 1TB
Samsung 970 evo plus 1TB m.2 SSD
```

The CPU was OCd to 5.0GHz and cooled with a Corsair H150i Pro

The RAM was OCd to 4133MHz CL 16

I have reset the cmos so now every component runs at stock speed.

Here is a list of every error I got :

```
PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA
IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL
KMODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED
SYSTEM_PTE_MISUSE
KERNEL_AUTO_BOOST_INVALID_LOCK_RELEASE
APC_INDEX_MISMATCH
KERNEL_SECURITY_CHECK_FAILURE
```

The two first errors are the ones I get consistently, especially the first one after each reboot.

Could the Motherboard or CPU be at fault?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Get the computer usable for a short period, update BIOS, Chipset, Video and restart. Now update all other drivers and then make sure Windows 10 is up to date.

Comment: [Over-clocking is dangerous](https://superuser.com/a/235278/8672). I think you undid it, but just too late.

Comment: It's been 2 days and I've never been able to reach windows sign in screen. For that reason I can't update any drivers.

Comment: Since you can get into the BIOS, remove all of the drives and try booting with your install CD just to see what happens.

Comment: You need to make plans to back up documents from your hard drive and re-install Windows if the above suggestions do not pan out.

Comment: If I boot from the CD, I can get on the screen where it asks for language, time zone, and keyboard. Then either install windows or repair. In both cases, I get a blue screen, no matter which drives are connected.
From time to time however, clicking on repair allows me to access the troubleshooting options. But no matter which option I choose, it always ends up in a blue screen after a few seconds.

For example, if I click "Automatic repair", it starts analyzing the computer and then blue screen.

If I choose command prompt, I start typing a command and I get a blue screen halfway through

Comment: I understand it does that with no matter what drive you use. I'm wondering what happens if you use no hard drives at all. I've had a similar symptoms happen when my SATA controller went bad. By using just the CD, you could go through the install process. Once you click to install it will either BSOD again, or you'll be able to continue up to the point where it shows an error that no disk is found. If it doesn't BSOD, you could try the same process again with the SATA cable that was used for the hard drive. How your SATA cable/controller could have gone bad in this instance is beyond me.

Comment: Ok,
I removed every single SATA cable from my motherboard. I even removed the M.2 SSD.
I booted from a USB key, and was able to go through the whole Windows installation process for the first time. Well, obviously up until it noticed I didn't have any drive and I had to restart. 
So I thought you were onto something...

Unfortunately after the restart, I was never able to get it to work again.

I either get a blue screen a few seconds after the "press any key to boot from CD/DVD" prompt, or after I choose the language for windows and then select one of the two options.

Comment: Did you change any cable or port that the SATA cable for the CD drive was plugged into compared to when it worked the first time? Did you add any drives back after the restart? And yes, you would have hit that brick wall of getting through the process but having no drive. That was kind of the point. When responding use @DrZoo or whoevers user name so we get a notification about your response.

Comment: On another note, mine behaved the same way. I could sometimes get part of the way through the install process and during the time Windows would copy files, I got a BSOD. Other times I couldn’t even get it to boot to my install media. After I replaced the motherboard, everything was fine.

Comment: @DrZoo yeah I'm going to return the Motherboard and hopefully they'll change it (bought it only 3 months ago). Thanks for everything.

Comment: @DrZoo I've changed motherboard and I still have the same problem. I'm starting to lose my mind. I'll return the cpu as well and if it doesn't work after that then maybe there are corrupted files in my PC case or in the thermal paste

Comment: Sorry to hear that. You could try making a new install media, but I don’t think that’s it. Since you don’t have a new CPU yet, you could try using known good SATA cable. At this point I think it may end up being your CPU.